# How to send an image from Azure Function (HTTP trigger) in Python to some front-end framework in HTTP response?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have created an API in Azure Function using python and I want to send an image placed in temp directory of azure function to front-end.

Answer (score -2):

```
# Send the blob to frontend
with open(image_location, 'rb') as f:
    image_blob = f.read()

.
.
.

return jsonify({"image_blob " : image_blob}
```